# How can I get daydream mode to remain active throughout the night when using the wireless charger?

Tags: nexus-4, daydream

Daydream mode is working as it should on a stock Nexus 4 4.2 device using the wireless charger however after a period of time daydream mode will shut off and put the screen in to sleep mode. This is not very conducive to being used as a clock in the middle of the night and thus I need to determine how I can get it to remain active throughout the evening, for an indeterminate amount of time.

I believe this is occurring after the phone reaches a certain charge, power delivery is suspended at which time once the sleep threshold is reached the phone will turn off, unless charging resumes. I could in theory set the sleep time to 30 minutes but would prefer a more elegant option.

Comment: @Al Everett Why was the Jelly Bean tag removed? The tag states, _Android 4.2 is an incremental update in the "Jelly Bean" version series which debuted with the Nexus 4 and Nexus 10. Please only use this tag if you feel your question is specific to Android 4.2_ which this question is specific to...

Comment: Your question is specific to Daydream. That that's the version where it was implemented is only incidental to the question. Presumably Android 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, etc., will also have the Daydream function.

Comment: It's specific to the OEM wireless charger which is specific to the Nexus 4 as power is not suspended from a USB power source but is suspended from the charger. Perhaps a wireless-charger tag would suffice but did not exist. The wireless charger is the unique piece here, not daydream, thus the addition of the jelly bean tag at minimum got it close to narrowing in on just the Nexus 4.

Comment: Are you sure it's got anything to do with the wireless charger? Have you tried with a wired charger? Tags should describe the _question_ not the _device/environment_.

Comment: I don't feel like arguing. If you think the tag belongs then put it back. Just don't be surprised if [someone else takes it out](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#editing).

Answer (score 1):

Since wireless charging actually stops charging at 100%, daydream will not stay active.  There's a open issue for this at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=48980

As a workaround, you can root your phone and, go to a command prompt and type the following:

```
su
svc power stayon true
```